# Hardhat connection timeout

Tags: node.js, solidity, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

## Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Connect Timeout Error

I have this problem when i want to fork net(goerli, main or others) with hardhat, but when i run my tests, that should be on forked net, it doest work and shows me this error.

Here is my hardhat.config.js code:

```
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks:{
        hardhat:{
            loggingEnabled: false,
            forking: {
                url: process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL
            }
        },
        goerli:{
            url: process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [ process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ]           
        },
        mumbai: {
            url: process.env.MUMBAI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [ process.env.MUMBAI_PRIVATE_KEY, process.env.MUMBAI_PRIVATE_KEY_2  ]     
        },
        localhost: {
            url: "HTTP://127.0.0.1:5500",
            timeout: 100_000_000
        },
    },
```

I tried to run local node in terminal by "npx hardhat node" and it works. But when i run "npx hardhat node --fork https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/" it shows me that error code again. What problem can be?

Comment: What is the value of your `GOERLI_RPC_URL` environment variable?

Comment: can you paste the entire error?

Answer (score 0):

Your "hardhat" default is already set to forking with the RPC you set in your `.env` for `GOERLI_RPC_URL`.

I would imagine running `npx hardhat node` will already run the fork

The reason your command `npx hardhat node --fork https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/` is failing is mostlikely because you didn't append it with your API key

also try adding this to end of your config:

```
 mocha: {
        timeout: 200000, // 200 seconds max for running tests
    },
```